# RPi 3 as Wireless Hotspot (hostapd): nl80211 driver initialization failed

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, wifi, wireless-adapter

I'm trying to create a WiFI Extender with my RPi3. I'm using a TP Link TL-WN722N external adapter. The setup is as follows:

```
Some WiFI -> TP-Link Adapter (wlan1) -> RPi -> Onboard RPi WiFi (wlan0) -> Extended Wifi
```

I used [this](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/) tutorial. And all other relevant files are configured the same way as in the tutorial.

The RPi connects fine to the `Some WiFI` and the wifi adapter works fine, but the problem occurs when I try to start `hosapd`.

**Running hostapd**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo /usr/sbin/hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf -d
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
rfkill: initial event: idx=1 type=2 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x1018 subcmd=1
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: interface wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 3 to mode 3: -19 (No such device)
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 3 to mode 2: -19 (No such device)
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
```

**/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf**

```
interface=wlan0
ssid=SomeSsid
hw_mode=g
channel=6
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_passphrase=mypass
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Why doesn't hostapd want to start? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You know, I came here to ask exactly the same question.  I'm surprised that nobody has seen fit to answer over the past year.  If this comment doesn't move this question to the front page I guess I'll re-post.